# How to parse Firebase DataSnapshot value correctly

Tags: java, android, parsing, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have to receive a `username` that has a `fullName` equal to "Bobby". So I'm trying to get data from Firebase Database using the following syntax:

```
ref.orderByChild("fullName").equalTo("Bobby").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {...}
```

What I get from `dataSnapshot.getValue()` is this:

```
{id3={username=bob, score=150, fullName=Bobby}}
```

I would like to know what is the best or correct way to get the `username` if I do not know which `id` number was returned?

Currently I'm achieving it this way:

```
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("Scores");

    ref.orderByChild("fullName").equalTo("Bobby").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.i(TAG, "dataSnapshot value = "+dataSnapshot.getValue());
            if(dataSnapshot.hasChildren()){
                Iterator<DataSnapshot> iter = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
                DataSnapshot snap = iter.next();
                if(snap.hasChildren() && snap.getValue() instanceof HashMap) {
                    HashMap map = (HashMap) snap.getValue();
                    if(map.containsKey("username")) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "onDataChange: username = " + map.get("username"));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

**EDIT:**
The Database structure is looking like this:

```
     {
      "Scores" : {
        "id1" : {
          "fullName" : "Robert",
          "score" : 96,
          "username" : "rob"
        },
        "id2" : {
          "fullName" : "Michael",
          "score" : 87,
          "username" : "mike"
        },
        "id3" : {
          "fullName" : "Bobby",
          "score" : 150,
          "username" : "bob"
        }
      }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

**SUMMARY:**

Using *wilkas'* answer I came to the following code snippet to get the wanted result:

```
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("Scores");

    ref.orderByChild("fullName").equalTo("Bobby").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.i(TAG, "dataSnapshot value = "+dataSnapshot.getValue());
            if(dataSnapshot.hasChildren()){
                Iterator<DataSnapshot> iter = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
                while (iter.hasNext()){
                    DataSnapshot snap = iter.next();
                    String nodId = snap.getKey();
                    String username = (String) snap.child("username").getValue();

                    //received results
                    Log.i(TAG, username + " on nod " + nodId);
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

It works well when several entries have a `fullName` equal to `'Bobby'`.

Comment: Post your entire json structure

Comment: Please post a representative snippet of your JSON (as text, not as a screenshot). You can easily get this by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you add listener under `Scores`, your childs are `id1`, `id2` and `id3`. By adding query `.orderByChild("fullName").equalTo("Bobby")` you filter by subchild and get one result `id3`. So your first `datasnapshot` refers to one child `id3` (though there could be more children if they would have same name of "Bobby").

In order to get the username, you need to iterate each received child (as you correctly do) - in this case only one child is iterated - and then get child `username` of that iterated child.

Since you know that every `idX` contains these children: `username`, `score`, `fullName`. You can easily extract `username` as follows (in your case `snap` is  reference to child `id3`):

```
String username = (String) snap.child("username").getValue();
String fullName = (String) snap.child("fullName").getValue();
long score = (long) snap.child("score").getValue();
```

Furthermore you can retrieve `id` too as follows:

```
String recordId = snap.getKey();
```

Within the inner iteration you could also get `username` as follows:

```
String recordId = snap.getKey();
String username = (String) dataSnapshot.child(recordId).child("username").getValue();
```